# How to use the ctrl+alt+X, J shortcut in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-juno

In Eclipse, how can I use a shortcut to launch the project as an application? I can get the menu but then I must select with a mouse, the "J" key is not working or I don't know how to use it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=369860) in Eclipse Juno. The workaround is:

Alt+Shift+X, then "Escape" key, then "J".